# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting - Reversing green>red scale

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to a group of sales goal numbers, specifically the amount that a particular person has already achieved. Obviously the higher the number (money they've brought in), the greener I want it to be.

The problem is, every color scale has a reversed version except the green>red one:
[image]

I could've sworn there used to be a reverse on. I've tried just setting the min point to a high number, and the max to a low number, but understandably that isn't working.

Any ideas on how I can reverse this so the low numbers show in red, and higher shows in green? Or am I stuck using one of the bottom left/right corner formatting options with white in the middle (looks kind of ugly on my sheet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you choose that one, you can just switch Red and Green in the dialog box color picker next to "Min value" and "Max value"

[image]

Comment: Ahhh so simple! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks Matt.